# JSON.NET causing VerificationException Operation could destabilize the runtime

Tags: .net, wcf, json.net, iis-7.5

Recently in one of the Web Applications, we started getting VerificationException while trying to serialize an object using JSON.NET.

I understand that JSON.NET enables CLR verification because it uses `[assembly: AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers]` ,but all below code samples throw same exception

```
1) JsonConvert.SerializeObject(log);

2) var settings = new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            Formatting = Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented
        };

3) var traceWriter = new MemoryTraceWriter();
```

It happens on specific machine (A) and not on the other (B), below what I did to isolate the problem:-

1. Execute Code A on machine B works not vice versa.
2. Compared installed .NET versions between A and B.
3. Compared installed features,roles, IIS settings between the two machines.
4. Implemented a small console which uses JSON.NET and it worked normally on machine A.
5. Used PEverify and SecAnnotation and everything seems fine.
6. Did a clean installation of Frameworks with no success.
7. Tried installing couple of .NET KBs.

.NET 4.7.1

JSON.NET 10.0.3

IIS 7.5

Windows Server 2008 R2

**Edit 1**
ToString Output

```
System.Security.VerificationException: Operation could destabilize the runtime.
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Object value)
```

**Edit 2**
Call stack from DebugDiag

```
    KERNELBASE!RaiseException+3d 
MSVCR120_CLR0400!CxxThrowException+c3 
clr!NGenCreateNGenWorker+d33c 
clr!TranslateSecurityAttributes+82981 
[[HelperMethodFrame]] 
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(System.Object)+15
```

What might be the reason of the exception?

Comment: There was a change to `MemoeyTraceWriter` in [release 10.0.3](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/releases/tag/10.0.3): *Fix - Fixed MemoryTraceWriter thread safety*.  What happens if you 1) Revert to 10.0.2?  2) Remove use of `MemoryTraceWriter`?  Also, can you share the full `ToString()` output of the exception including the exception type, message, traceback and inner exception?

Comment: It's not related to JSON.NET as the WebApp works on environment B and WebApp from Server B throw same problem on Server A.

Regarding the code samples, I am just saying that application crashes immediately when hitting of any of the lines consuming JSON.NET.

I edited the question with ToString Output!